# React-Apollo error only shows status code 500

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am wondering how I can access my throw errors in my frontend with react-apollo?

My simple resolver for fetching a single customer is like this, where `args._id` is the customer ID. Now if the id is not valid react-apollo just throws an 500 error.

> Error! Network error: Response not successful: Received status code
>   500

```
   customer: async (args, req) => {
        const validateId = (id) => {
            return mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)
        }
        if(args._id && validateId(args._id)){
            try { 

                const customer = await Customer
                    .findById(args._id)

                return transformCustomer(customer)
            }
            catch (err) {
                throw err
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("error")
        }
    },
```

I tried using errorPolicy="all" and accessing error.graphQLErrors, but that dosn't work, because it throws a 500 error.

> Cannot read property 'graphQLErrors' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (in addiition to wrapping in a try/catch) - Perhaps you should be checking whether _id is valid before sending a request to the server:

```
customer: async (args, req) => {
    // do some validation on _id
    if (args._id && isValid(args._id) ) {
        try {
            const customer = await Customer.findById(args._id)
        } catch (e) {
          // handle server error
        }
    } else {
       // handle invalid _id here
    }
```

Comment: I need to check with the server if the _id is valid? So I thought that `if(!customer)`and throwing an error if it's not valid would work?

Comment: no - because the error has already been thrown when you check `if(!customer` - which is why you need to wrap it in try/catch. If you *need* to send it to the server to check it then ignore the above..

Comment: But if it throws a 500 server error each time, and Apollo Client ALWAYS renders "Error! Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500" when this happens? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

To catch an error thrown by apollo you need to wrap the call that executes the query into a `try`-`catch`.

In your example this is probably:

```
try {
    const customer = await Customer.findById(args._id);
} catch(err) {
    // handle the error
}
```

However a `500` is always a programming error and should be fixed on the server. It seems your server doesn't do the required validation before using the parameters passed in the query.

Comment: How do you suggest that I check if the ID is an existing document? I am using Mongoose and when using Graphiql, I get the error message. But when using Apollo Client, I only get the network error.